# Java number format exception.

Tags: java, netbeans

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "P35.00"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at OrderSystems.OrderSystem.jButton3MouseClicked(OrderSystem.java:419)
at OrderSystems.OrderSystem.access$900(OrderSystem.java:14)
at OrderSystems.OrderSystem$10.mouseClicked(OrderSystem.java:241)
```

I keep getting this error after i clicked the jButton3. heres my codes.

```
private void jButton3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
double sub = Double.parseDouble(sub_field.getText());
double vat = Double.parseDouble(vat_field.getText());
double allTotal = (sub + vat);
String iTotal = String.format("%.2f", allTotal);       
total_field.setText(iTotal);
}
```

This is the code for the sub_field and vat_field

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
double ham = Double.parseDouble(ham_field.getText());
  double burger = Double.parseDouble(burger_field.getText());
  double bacon = Double.parseDouble(bacon_field.getText());


    double bac = bacon * 5;
    double harm = ham * 10;
    double burg = burger *20;

    double sub = harm + burg + bac;
    String sub_com = String.format("P%.2f", sub);
    sub_field.setText(sub_com);

}
```

Comment: what part of error message is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.NumberFormatException` is pretty clear: "P35.00" is not a number.
This Exception is thrown when the paramether for the parsing `Double.parseDouble` is not what it is excpecting.

Try out removing the P from 35.00 and see if it works.

It is also common practice to surround it with a try-catch block to prompt to the user what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is crashing because your input string is "P35.00" and you try to parse that into a double. Remove the 'P' and it should work because the compiler will not parse a P into a double.